# t-sql query not showing expected result

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have sales table data as shown below

[Sales Table Data http://lh5.ggpht.com/_KT7tmVVBHFM/TCryAax1JlI/AAAAAAAAAFk/zahMq4RoOuw/s144/Sales.png](http://lh5.ggpht.com/_KT7tmVVBHFM/TCryAax1JlI/AAAAAAAAAFk/zahMq4RoOuw/s144/Sales.png)

I want it to display group wise sales according to Date. Sales table contains data for different groups but my query shows only two rows.

**The SQL Query:**

```
select 
    i.gName, 
    sum(Quantity) as '180ml', 
    isnull((select sum(Quantity)
        from saleslog 
        where BillDate='12-10-2010' 
        and pSize=375 and pGroup=i.gCode),0) as '375ml', 
    isnull((select sum(Quantity)
        from saleslog 
        where BillDate='12-10-2010' 
        and pSize=500 and pGroup=i.gCode),0) as '500ml', 
    isnull((select sum(Quantity)
        from saleslog 
        where BillDate='12-10-2010' 
        and pSize=750 and pGroup=i.gCode),0) as '750ml', 
    isnull((select sum(Quantity)
        from saleslog 
        where BillDate='12-10-2010' 
        and pSize=1000 and pGroup=i.gCode),0) as '1000ml', 
    isnull((select sum(Quantity)
        from saleslog 
        where BillDate='12-10-2010' 
        and pSize=2000 and pGroup=i.gCode),0) as '2000ml' 
from saleslog as s
    inner join ItemGroup as i on s.pGroup=i.gCode 
where BillDate='12-10-2010' 
    and i.gCode=pGroup 
    and pSize=180 
group by i.gCode,i.gName
```

**Output of above query**

```
WHISKY 5 2 0 0 0 0
RUM     82 0 0 45 0 0
```

It is showing these results, but I expected it to list all product groups as follows:

**Product Group Table :**

```
1 BRANDY         1
2 WHISKY         2
3 RUM         3
4 GIN         4
5 VODKA         5
6 BEER         8
7 WINE         6
8 LIQUOR         7
9 SCOTCH WHY 9
10 LUBRICANT 15
11 UNTAXABLE 16
12 O/S LIQUOR 10
13 RTD         11
14 275 ML         12
```

What's wrong with my query?

Comment: Love the thumbnail of the data. Too bad it is too small to read. You could also think about formatting that massive SQL statement so it is not on one line and can be read without scrolling.

Comment: Could you break your query into a few more lines, please? One long line is hard to read and understand.

Comment: Agreed, you need to sort it out so that we can see what data is there

Comment: @Oded : you can click on thumbnail for full image.....

Comment: did you even try that? I clicked it, and guess what. I get a tiny, unreadable thumbnail all by itself in my browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I think you need to move the 180mL query into a subquery with the others. Something like this:

```
select i.gName,
isnull((select sum(Quantity)from saleslog where BillDate='12-10-2010' and pSize=180 and pGroup=i.gCode),0) as '180ml', 
isnull((select sum(Quantity)from saleslog where BillDate='12-10-2010' and pSize=375 and pGroup=i.gCode),0) as '375ml', 
isnull((select sum(Quantity)from saleslog where BillDate='12-10-2010' and pSize=500 and pGroup=i.gCode),0) as '500ml',
isnull((select sum(Quantity)from saleslog where BillDate='12-10-2010' and pSize=750 and pGroup=i.gCode),0) as '750ml',
isnull((select sum(Quantity)from saleslog where BillDate='12-10-2010' and pSize=1000 and pGroup=i.gCode),0) as '1000ml',
isnull((select sum(Quantity)from saleslog where BillDate='12-10-2010' and pSize=2000 and pGroup=i.gCode),0) as '2000ml' 
from saleslog as s 
inner join ItemGroup as i on s.pGroup=i.gCode 
where BillDate='12-10-2010' 
group by i.gCode, i.gName
```

Comment: OK its showing all group, thanks..

programming, 1 code error or misplace can do havoc. thanks again for prompt reply....

Comment: But if there's not SalesLog record for an item on 12-10-2010, then no record will be returned for that group still.

Answer (score 1):

What datatype is this `BillDate`??

If it is `DATETIME`, then this statement here

```
BillDate = '12-10-2010'
```

will only select those purchases made on 12-10-2010 at midnight (0:00:00 hours).

You need to be more careful with your date queries! DATETIME **always** also contains a time portion - so if you want all purchases on the 12-10-2010, you need to use:

```
WHERE BillDate BETWEEN '12-10-2010 00:00:00' AND  '12-10-2010 23:59:59'
```

or alternatively:

```
WHERE DAY(BillDate) = 12 AND MONTH(BillDate) = 10 AND YEAR(BillDate) = 2010
```

Comment: Good point - though I'd use: 
BillDate >= '2010-10-12' AND BillDate < '2010-10-13'
as I've seen records missed before from the last second of the day with the BETWEEN approach (i.e. any records 23:59:59.001 to 23:59:59.999(

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your FROM clause onwards to:

```
from ItemGroup as i
    LEFT OUTER JOIN saleslog as s ON i.gCode = s.pGroup AND s.BillDate = '12-10-2010' AND s.pSize=180
group by i.gCode,i.gName
```

Answer (score 0):

That query makes no sense semantically but works once you think hard about it.

For instance:

You are selecting the SUM of all sales for the group as your 180ml:

```
sum(Quantity) as '180ml'
```

But you are conditioning by the size of 180ml on the total to counter that

```
where pSize=180
```

I would say it is because the other groups don't have 180ml sizes for sale.

Answer (score 0):

You query only returns product groups which have at least 1 180ml sale. Change the INNER JOIN to a subselect, as you did with the other product sizes, and you will get all product groups in the result set.